# For each object in array in perl

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop through each object in an array in Perl and I think I am making an obvious error.

```
my @members_array = [
    {
        id    => 1234,
        email => 'first@example.com',
    }, {
        id    => 4321,
        email => 'second@example.com',
    }
];

use Data::Dumper;
for my $member ( @members_array ) {
    print Dumper( $member );
}
```

Expected output for first iteration

```
{
    id    => 1234,
    email => 'first@example.com',
}
```

Actual output for first iteration

```
[{
    'email' => 'first@example.com',
    'id' => 1234
 }, {
    'email' => 'second@example.com',
    'id' => 4321
}];
```

How do I loop through these elements in the array? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ ... ]` is used to create an array reference; you need to use `( ... )` to create an array :

```
my @members_array = (
    {
        id    => 1234,
        email => 'first@example.com',
    }, {
        id    => 4321,
        email => 'second@example.com',
    }
);
```

And then the rest of your code will work just fine.

Comment: Yes, spot on, and how annoying! Thanks!

Comment: It happens! A fresh eye often helps, I'm glad mine did.